# Delete UITableViewCell and ALL of that cell's data

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UITableViewCell. I can add and subtract `1` from the cell's `textLabel` and I can also delete the cells. Here is my problem, Lets say i add 5 to the value of the `textLabel`. And this cell is at the 0 indexPath (The First cell in the table). When I delete this cell and there are now no longer any cells on the table, I add a new cell and this new cell automatically gets the same value as the cell that was just deleted. SO this new cell will have a value of `5` and i want the cell to have a value of 1 just like every cell should when it is added. This only happens when a cell is deleted and a new cell is added at that exact same indexPath.  So my question is: do i have to delete this cells "memory" or "data" for this to be fixed? Thanks a bunch for the help!

**CellForRowAtIndexPath**:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
     {
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
         addBtn = [[UIButton alloc]init];
         addBtn =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
         [addBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(220,10,25,55)];
         [addBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(addLabelText:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
         [addBtn setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         [addBtn setEnabled:YES];
         [cell addSubview:addBtn];

         subBtn = [[UIButton alloc]init];
         subBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
         [subBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(260,10,25,55)];
         [subBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(subtractLabelText:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
         [subBtn setTitle:@"-" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         [subBtn setEnabled:YES];
         [cell addSubview:subBtn];

         //cell.textLabel.text = @"1";


    } 
    //cellText.hidden=!self.editing;
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    cell.imageView.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
    cell.textLabel.text = [number objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


return cell;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code for your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method?  It sounds like you are not configuring the value of your textLabel correctly in there after you `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`

Comment: post some code on your UITableView, where is the value of textLabel comes from? an array? or anything, also, it can possibly because the cell is being reused. Post your - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath if possible

Comment: @jonkroll sure i will post it now!

Comment: @jonkroll I was looking at `rob mayoff`'s answer and he seems to be right, in case he does not reply, may one of you two please point me in the right direction of how to "reset" the cell's `textLabel`? Thank you very much! :D

Comment: @xSlash I was looking at `rob mayoff`'s answer and he seems to be right, in case he does not reply, may one of you two please point me in the right direction of how to "reset" the cell's textLabel? Thank you very much! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When cells are deleted or go off screen, the table view saves them and reuses them later.  So you need to reset `textLabel`'s value in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.  The `UITableViewCell` class reference says this:

> The table view's delegate in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: should always reset all content when reusing a cell.

Comment: okay, how should i do this? Should i set the `cell.textLabel.text = @"1";` or is there another way to do this? also should i put it inside the `if(cell == nil)` statement? Thanks a lot for the help!!

Comment: please help! I have searched for the answer and i have looked in the documentation, thank you!

Comment: You need to initialize `cell.textLabel.text` to the value appropriate for `indexPath`.  Normally that means you need to use `indexPath.row` (and maybe `indexPath.section`) to look up the appropriate value in an array or a database table.

Comment: Since im very new to programming, im not too sure how to "initialize" `cell.textLabel.text`. May you please provide me with some sample code or the doccumentation where you learned this at? Thank you very much! i appreciate the help rob!!  +1

Comment: I learned it from the [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html).  If that document is too advanced for you, you need to work through some basic tutorials or choose a simpler project.

Comment: okay thanks a bunch! i have been programming for about 2 years, but i haven't dealt with table view at all! Thanks again for the help rob!!